# Math for zoom to cursor on mouse wheel scrolling

Tags: graphics, zooming, directx-9, scrollwheel

Have to implement a **Directx9** project that involves **zoom towards the cursor** like **Google maps**  with the mouse scroll wheel
[(similar to  this implementation](http://phrogz.net/tmp/canvas_zoom_to_cursor.html) [by Phrogz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/405017/phrogz)).

Need the math and the variables required for the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this problem using below steps

- Decide per scroll movement, call it Z-SHIFT, in Z-direction towards the target point
  such that the camera should travel to target in fixed scrolls(SCROLL_COUNT)
- Calculate the distance to travel in X and Y directions, say DIST_X and DIST_Y
- Movement per scroll in X-direction and Y-direction will be calculated as

  - X-SHIFT = DIST_X/SCROLL_COUNT
  - Y-SHIFT = DIST_Y/SCROLL_COUNT
  - Z-SHIFT = Pre decided suitable value

We have mathematical equation to guide the coordinates of the camera per scroll which when placed in the code provides the required zoom to cursor effect.